mount options of udisks2 (dmask, fmask) are not applied when mounted with udisksctl (exfat fs)
I have a removable SD Card formatted with exfat which I would like to mount with udisksctlvia the udisks2 mechanism.
What I want to do is to replicate a noexec option by using dmask=0002 and fmask=0113.
I have the following line in /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf:
exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,dmask=0002,fmask=0113

When I check with a ls -al, these are not applied. Files have a .rwxr-xr-x (0755) permission and directories have drwxr-xr-x (0755).
What do I need to do to make udisks2 accept the configuration file and not ignore it? The options were written according to the latest storaged.org specifications.
All existing questions on https://unix.stackexchange.com do not have a solution. I hope that the collective mind now has better knowledge.

After some experimentation, I was able to find an answer.
The line
exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,dmask=0002,fmask=0113

alone is not enough. It needs to follow the .ini file syntax with a stanza name preceding a keyword, otherwise the udisks2 service gives an error message (with systemctl status udisks2.service or journalctl -u udisks2):
Error reading global mount options config file /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf: Key file does not start with a group

A proper .conf file would thus look like this:
### Mounting exfat and vfat devices with noexec option, ntfs3 no effect (!)
[defaults]
exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,dmask=0002,fmask=0113
# exfat_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,dmask,errors,fmask,iocharset,namecase,umask
vfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,dmask=0002,fmask=0113,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,flush
# vfat_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,flush,utf8,shortname,umask,dmask,fmask,codepage,iocharset,usefree,showexec
ntfs:ntfs3_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,dmask=0002,fmask=0113
# ntfs:ntfs3_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,umask,dmask,fmask,iocharset,discard,nodiscard,sparse,nosparse,hidden,nohidden,sys_immutable,nosys_immutable,showmeta,noshowmeta,prealloc,noprealloc,hide_dot_files,nohide_dot_files,windows_names,nocase,case

There is no need to reload the service with systemctl restart udisks2.service, the config file is read on each mount.
To observe the effect of changes to the .conf file, it's enough to use udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1 and then udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1.
When the file is properly formed, the log file/service status now contains a line
Using overridden mount options: uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,dmask=0002,fmask=0113

and the changes are effective for the newly mounted device. The commented 'allow' lines contain the default options of which to choose from. They can be further restricted for manual mounting by removing options and uncommenting.
As of now (2024-10-26, udisks2 2.10.1, kernel 6.11.0), this works for vfat and exfat. For reasons unknown, the ntfs3 driver still ignores this and mounts silently with the default options (ntfs:ntfs3_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID).

From the documentation you linked to:

The _defaults always need to be a subset of _allow. The _defaults
options are also merged with any extra options passed via the Mount()
method call.

The highlight above is mine.
What does your exfat_allow look like?

From the /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example:
# # common options for both the native kernel driver and exfat-fuse
# exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro
# exfat_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,dmask,errors,fmask,iocharset,namecase,umask
This doesn't look off. The options are a subset of _allow.

In case the exfat_allow line needs to be explicitly uncommented and put in the mount_options.conf file, I copied this over from the example file, unmounted and remounted. No change.
